# IBM Appscan giving issue with Xpath Compile

Tags: java, xpath, websphere

I am trying to read a tag from XML using Xpath. Below is the code for same.

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();  
XPath duplcatexpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();  
XPathExpression duplcatexpathexpr = duplcatexpath.compile(duplicateconditionpath);
```

Everything is working as expected but when i am running app scan it is giving vulnerability **Injection.XPath.**
Is there any way we will be able to mitigate this.

Comment: Exactly which line throws the vulnerability in AppScan ?

Comment: In brief, first make sure your application isn't vulnerable to XPath injection attacks, then configure the scan to suppress the warnings. Not sure which of those two steps you're having difficulty with.

Comment: @Som the third line shows the vulnerability.

Comment: @Michael XPath will be sitting in secrets actually so my application won't be vulnerable for Xpath Injections. But I can't suppress the scan warnings(maintained at org level).

Comment: Then you either have to stop using XPath because of the spurious warnings, or you have to live with the warnings. What else can we possibly say? Tools that scan for vulnerabilities like this are notoriously crude.